# Bootstrap4: issue with two dropdowns in burgermenu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4, hamburger-menu

While testing BS4 (v4.0.0-alpha.6) I stumbled across an odd issue on the standard template example, which I modified slightly by adding another dropdown (dropdown2) next to the original one (dropdown1).

```
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown02" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 2</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown02">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

If I shrink the window to get the burgermenu, dropdown2 won't be shown if dropdown1 is already open. I don't get the same behaviour on BS3 or if I have dropdown2 open and click dropdown1

I can't seem to see what causes this. Anyone got an idea?

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kimemax/dg2375bb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue in Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6.

You can track it here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21941

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing me towards this. I'm currently refactoring a site and was about to skip BS4 due to this behaviour.

Comment: sorry, i never ask questions, so i was looking around to find a way to accept your answer - so obvious with the checkmark that i couldn't see it... doh!